# How to tranpose columns in a grouped data in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by, transpose

I have a data frame (df) that is grouped by CompanyID (2 companies) and there is information by year (2006 and 2007).

```
df <- 
CompanyID  Name Country ISIN     Director2006 Gender2006 F2006 M2006 Findex2006 Fperce2006 Total2006 Blauindex2006 Director2007 Gender2007 F2007 M2007 Total2007 Findex2007 Blauindex2007 Fperce2007
25830   BANKxxx Austria AT000504 11734844255   M         2     3     1          0.4         5        0.48          11734844255   M         1     4      5           1        0.32          0.2
25830   BANKxxx Austria AT000504 1878371165    F         NA    NA    NA         NA          NA       NA            5524344997    F         NA    NA     NA          NA       NA            NA
25830   BANKxxx Austria AT000504 5524344997    F         NA    NA    NA         NA          NA       NA            5524354997    M         NA    NA     NA          NA       NA            NA
25830   BANKxxx Austria AT000504 5524354997    M         NA    NA    NA         NA          NA       NA            5742347684    M         NA    NA     NA          NA       NA            NA
25830   BANKxxx Austria AT000504 6613115791    M         NA    NA    NA         NA          NA       NA            40160443378   M         NA    NA     NA          NA       NA            NA
12339   BANKyyy Belgium AT034003 5524344997    M         0     2    0           0           2        0             5524344997    M         0     2      2           0        0             0
12339   BANKyyy Belgium AT034003 5524354997    M         NA    NA    NA         NA          NA       NA            5524354997    M         NA    NA     NA          NA       NA            NA
```

I would like to transpose some columns (Findex, Fperce, Blauindex and Total) for 2006 and 2007.

Thus, my expected output would look like:

```
df_final <-
Name     CompanyID  ISIN     Country  Year  Findex  Fperce  Blauindex  Total
BANKxxx  25830      AT000504 Austria  2006   1       0.4    0.48         5
                                      2007   1       0.2    0.32         5
BANKyyy  12339      AT034003 Belgium  2006   0       0      0            2
                                      2007   0       0      0            2
```

Please, can someone advise me? Thanks.

**DATA**

```
df <- read.table(text = 
        "CompanyID  Name    Country ISIN     Director2006 Gender2006 F2006 M2006 Findex2006 Fperce2006 Total2006 Blauindex2006 Director2007 Gender2007 F2007 M2007 Total2007 Findex2007 Blauindex2007 Fperce2007
         25830  BANKxxx Austria AT000504 11734844255   M         2     3     1          0.4         5        0.48          11734844255   M         1     4      5           1        0.32          0.2
         25830  BANKxxx Austria AT000504 1878371165    F         NA    NA    NA         NA          NA       NA            5524344997    F         NA    NA     NA          NA       NA            NA
         25830  BANKxxx Austria AT000504 5524344997    F         NA    NA    NA         NA          NA       NA            5524354997    M         NA    NA     NA          NA       NA            NA
         25830  BANKxxx Austria AT000504 5524354997    M         NA    NA    NA         NA          NA       NA            5742347684    M         NA    NA     NA          NA       NA            NA
         25830  BANKxxx Austria AT000504 6613115791    M         NA    NA    NA         NA          NA       NA            40160443378   M         NA    NA     NA          NA       NA            NA
         12339  BANKyyy Belgium AT034003 5524344997    M         0     2    0           0           2        0             5524344997    M         0     2      2           0        0             0
         12339  BANKyyy Belgium AT034003 5524354997    M         NA    NA    NA         NA          NA       NA            5524354997    M         NA    NA     NA          NA       NA            NA",
        header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a `dplyr`/`tidyr`-based workflow. I'm selecting the columns you're interested in, using `matches` to give regex to match column names to save having to write out "Findex2006", "Findex2007", etc. This is especially handy if you end up with more than just these two years to work with. Then I gathered the data into a long format, excluding `CompanyID` through `ISIN`. Then `separate` with `sep = -4` splits `measure` (e.g. "Findex2006") into two columns, where the value for the second column begins 4 characters from the end of each string (e.g. "Findex" and "2006"). There were some `NA` in there that I filtered out, then `spread` brings it back into a wide shape, but with column no longer based on year.

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
    select("CompanyID", "Name", "Country", "ISIN", matches("Findex|Fperce|Blauindex|Total")) %>%
    gather(key = measure, value = value, -CompanyID:-ISIN) %>%
    separate(measure, into = c("measure", "Year"), sep = -4) %>%
    filter(!is.na(value)) %>%
    spread(key = measure, value = value)
#>   CompanyID    Name Country     ISIN Year Blauindex Findex Fperce Total
#> 1     12339 BANKyyy Belgium AT034003 2006      0.00      0    0.0     2
#> 2     12339 BANKyyy Belgium AT034003 2007      0.00      0    0.0     2
#> 3     25830 BANKxxx Austria AT000504 2006      0.48      1    0.4     5
#> 4     25830 BANKxxx Austria AT000504 2007      0.32      1    0.2     5
```

**Updated for `tidyr` v1.0.0:** The `pivot` functions make the syntax here cleaner, allowing for splitting names as part of the reshaping.

```r
df %>%
  dplyr::filter(!is.na(F2006)) %>%
  pivot_longer(-CompanyID:-ISIN, names_to = c(".value", "Year"), 
               names_pattern = "(^[A-Za-z]+)(\\d{4}$)") %>% 
  dplyr::select(-Gender:-M)
```